# Использование XSLT в XML

Tags: java, xml, spring, rest, xslt

Здравствуйте пишу web приложение c REST API и представлением в виде XSLT преобразования полученной xml от REST api. Генерирую xml в коде на сервере, хочу чтобы она рендерилась в браузере клиента по определенному стилю используя XSLT. Приложение развертывается на веб сервере. Как верно указать ссылку href в заголовке xml чтобы она подцепила xslt файл который лежит в resources приложения?

При обычном указании ссылки на файл xslt в xml например: href/pack1/1.xslt при рендеринге xml браузер делает запрос на эту ссылку, а мне нужно чтобы подцепился локальный файл: 1.xslt который лежит в resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решением было переопределить метод в конфигурации web для доступа к статическим ресурсам:

```
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){}
```

Почитать можно здесь:
https://o7planning.org/ru/10353/configuring-static-resources-in-spring-mvc#a426877